# Unix concatenate nested/indented list of values?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to generate a hierarchical list from a list of key-value pairs with indentation (2 spaces). *modified original content*

EDIT: apologies. I ended up pasting the wrong output. the original yaml file is of this format. getting the "description" is my secondary target :

```
schemas:
- name: exports
  tables:
  - name: sugar
    description: makes stuff sweet
    active_date: 2019-01-07 00:00:00
    columns:
    - name: color
      type: abcd
    - name: taste
      type: abcd
      description: xyz
      example: 21352352
    - name: structure
      type: abcd
      description: xyzasaa
      example: 10001
  - name: salt
    description: not that sweet.
      makes it salty.
    active_date: 2018-12-18 00:00:00
    columns:
    - name: strength
      type: abcdef
      description: easy to find
      example: 2018-03-03 12:30:00
    - name: color
      type: abcdeffa
      description: not sweet
      example: 21352352
    - name: quality
      type: abcd
      description: how much is needed
      example: 10001
```

The best desired output would be below, where I am trying to generate a csv and flatten the yaml with each row carrying the child most element with all parent values:

```
sugar.color,abcd
sugar.taste,abcd,xyz
sugar.structure,abcd,xyzasaa
salt.strength,abcdef,"easy to find"
salt.color,abcdeffa,"not sweet"
salt.quality,abcd,"how much is needed"
```

but I am not aware how feasible the above is ,so looking for at least:

```
sugar.color
sugar.taste
sugar.structure
salt.strength
salt.color
salt.quality
```

Comment: Why do the `- desc` lines show up? The positive look-behind doesn't match them.

Comment: Show the contents of `export.yaml` that you want to get that output from. The right solution won't have an intermediate `grep` step so showing the output of `grep` isn't useful.

Comment: Apologies. I ended up pasting the wrong grep output. 

The original file content added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }

match($0,/^ +- /) { indent = RLENGTH }

$1 == "-" {
    prt()
    if (indent == 4) {
        key = $NF
        subKey = ""
    }
    else if (indent == 6) {
        subKey = $NF
    }
    next
}

subKey != "" {
    data = substr($0,indent+1)

    if ( data ~ /^[^[:space:]]/ ) {
        # new data
        tag = data
        sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^:]+: */,"",data)
        f[tag] = data
    }
    else {
        # continuation of previous data
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"",data)
        f[tag] = f[tag] " " data
    }
}

END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( "type" in f ) {
        print key "." subKey, f["type"], "\"" f["description"] "\""
    }
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
sugar.color,abcd,""
sugar.taste,abcd,"xyz"
sugar.structure,abcd,"xyzasaa"
salt.strength,abcdef,"easy to find"
salt.color,abcdeffa,"not sweet"
salt.quality,abcd,"how much is needed"
```

If any `description` is multi-line the above will concatenate it onto one line.

Comment: Thank you! This works as expected...I am getting the "name" hierarchy elements. Any chance of also collecting the "description" and "type" values IF THEY EXIST for a child element? 

Also, can you please explain the awk expression? It would help me learn :)

Comment: Excellent! This is great... Thank you for your help :) 
Would you mind sharing the explanation of the awk expressions you used and how you formatted the output?

Comment: You're welcome. I really think you can figure it out for yourself though. Think about it, add some "prints" to dump some values if you like, then ask if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl script that produces your desired output.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/postderef/;
no warnings qw/experimental::postderef/; # Suppress warning on 5.20 and 5.22
use YAML::XS qw/LoadFile/;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $yaml = LoadFile($ARGV[0]);
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({quote_space => 1, eol => "\n"});

for my $schema ($yaml->{'schemas'}->@*) {
    for my $table ($schema->{'tables'}->@*) {
        for my $col ($table->{'columns'}->@*) {
            my @row = ("$table->{name}.$col->{name}", $col->{type});
            push @row, $col->{'description'} if exists $col->{'description'};
            $csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@row);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$ perl example.pl test.yaml
sugar.color,abcd
sugar.taste,abcd,xyz
sugar.structure,abcd,xyzasaa
salt.strength,abcdef,"easy to find"
salt.color,abcdeffa,"not sweet"
salt.quality,abcd,"how much is needed"
```

Requires a couple of non-standard modules: [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS)  (Debian/Ubuntu package `libyaml-libyaml-perl`) and [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) (Debian/Ubuntu `libtext-csv-xs-perl`)

---

YAML is a structured data markup format, and trying to do things with it a line at a time using regular expressions or the like is setting yourself up for failure; any input that varies from what you expect will cause it to fail miserably; and the lack of context in the bigger picture and lots of edge cases make it impossible to be robust. Same for trying to parse things like CSV, XML/HTML or JSON with regular expressions.

You're better off using a tool or library that understands the format. So the above uses a YAML parser to convert your file into the equivalent perl data structure, and then walks that, printing out the relevant values. It uses a CSV library to format the output to avoid having to manually deal with quoting fields with spaces like your desired output does, and all the other edge cases like quotes in the fields.

Comment: Excellent! This looks promising, and I did find similar solutions like PyYAML. :) however there are reasons why I cannot use this approach, mainly for 1. difficult to request additional libraries, so looking for native sed/awk solution. 2. the input yaml file is always going to be of fixed format, so not really looking for one key for all types of yaml. 

Although not quite my answer ,given the considerations, the output is exactly what I am looking for